# Python reduce list of string to int

Tags: python, functools

I have a list of words and I am trying to compute the total length of all words combined.
Why is my code:

```
words = ["a", "ab", 'adsf']                                             
    
wordlen = reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) + len(y), words)
```

giving me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  wordlen = reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) + len(y), words)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Your function returns an `int`. From the second iteration onwards of `reduce`, the `x` argument gets the previous return value (which is an int...). That's just how `reduce` works

Comment: @Tomerikoo isnt that a strange implementation of reduce? It is a bit different from my experience with reduce in other languages.

Comment: No I don't think it is, and anyway it is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). It *reduces* the iterable to a single value by applying the function on first 2 elements, and then applying it on the result and the next element cumulatively. This implies that the arguments and return value need to have the same type

Answer (score 3):

Below is a little different approach to the problem:

```
words = ['zz','abc']
total_len = sum(len(x) for x in words)
print(total_len)
```

output

```
5
```

Comment: Or in a more functional fashion: `print(sum(map(len, words)))`

Comment: But the question is not how to do that, it is why the provided method doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), use initializer parameter and remove first `len()`:

```
from functools import reduce

words = ['Hello', 'World', 'This', 'Is', 'Example']

wordlen = reduce(lambda x, y: x + len(y), words, 0)

print(wordlen)
```

Prints:

```
23
```

Comment: @DeepSpace If length of `words` is 2 then it works, otherwise it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Tomerikoo's comment, I did a deeper research on reduce (aka fold). Many of the reduce/fold implementations in other languages require the operation to be associative. When the operation is associative, the order it is applied does not matter. For example, len("a") + len("b") + len("c") generates same results wherever you put the parenthesis (because integer addition on a finite field is associative).

The confusion happens when the operation is not associative. In this case the order the function is applied matters. This is when the concept of left fold and right fold comes in. They are both ways that stipulate how parenthesis is added.

Also note that fold requires two functions:
Function i that converts an object of type A to another of type B and
Functoin ii that reduces multiple type B objects into one single object of type C.

Left fold and right fold essentially use pairwise operations, which allows one to combine the two functions into one. This is the idea of @Andrej Kesely's answer.